# How to translate functions like get_the_date()?

Tags: translation, date

My wordpress website has two languages. The theme translates properly, but whenever I use `get_the_date` it is in the default english language. How do I force the use of another language?
The [locale filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/locale) **does not** work.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it in plain PHP?

For example, you can write a function like:

```
function get_the_german_date($date = '', $post = null) {
    $d = get_the_date($date, $post);
    if ($d) {
        $d = new DateTime($d);
        return $d->format('d.m.Y');
    } else return false;
}
```

Similary, if you want to follow the WordPress standards:

```
function the_german_date($date = '', $post = null) {
    $d = get_the_date($date, $post);
    if ($d) {
        $d = new DateTime($d);
        echo $d->format('d.m.Y');
    }
}
```

I realize this may be too much work since you want to do it dynamically depending on your locale, but you can do a check of your locale, or you can have a global date function where if website is in english you output `get_the_date` and if not the function above.

Comment: Thanks but I need the translation from WordPress for the months

Comment: I found the solution and posted it :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', function() {
    switch_to_locale(get_current_language());
    add_filter('locale', function() {
        return get_current_language() ? get_current_language() : "en_US";
    });
    load_theme_textdomain('default', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
});
```

The sequence is quite important, that the locale filter is defined before `load_theme_textdomain` and `switch_to_locale` is called before defining the filter.
`get_current_language` is a function I wrote, which defined the language from the url.